# Pandas - Replacing a specific value in all columns with the corresponding value in another column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning

I have a feature vector (dummy) dataframe for categorical data in Pandas, and I have appended a 'ratings' column to that dataframe which represents continuous data from 1 to 10. How do I replace all the 1s in all the columns except the 'ratings' column with the corresponding 'ratings' column value?

I'm using this feature in my multiple linear regression model. Is this a good practice? In machine learning/statistical analysis concepts, what would this approach be called?

Comment: Is there a reason for the r tag?

Comment: Nope, other than the fact that if this is a common approach in statistical analysis concept, r programmers could probably help me out!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by multiplying the dummies `dataframe` by the ratings column --assuming i understand you correctly-- try this:

```
import pandas as pd
# mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( {'alpha':['a','a','b','b','c','e','f','g'],'rating':[1,3,5,7,1,5,10,1]})
# get dummies
df = pd.get_dummies(df)
# multiply dataframe by ratings 
df.ix[:, 1:].mul(df['rating'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
    a   b   c   e   f   g
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   3   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   5   0   0   0   0
3   0   7   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   5   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   10  0
7   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

As for whether this is useful- does it improve the metric you are using to evaluate your model? Also worth posting on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: row.replace(1, row['rating']), axis=1)
```